# I don’t know if I have gotten through puberty and if my sins that i commit know are written down

Tags: sin, masturbation, children

Assalam walaikum, I'm a male 13 years old. (I am really embarrassed to say this) but i have masturbated and i don’t know if it is a sin because I don’t know if I have gotten through puberty, for that sin to count. Please tell me if it counts and can a child do sins until the time of puberty is finished or until puberty starts? On the internet it says puberty starts between 9-14, so i have already started but that is why I wanted to know if the sins count until the end of puberty?

Comment: If you can masturbate then you have reached puberty. Puberty is not defined by age but by physical symptoms such as wet dreams, ejaculation, pubic hair etc.

Answer (score 0):

These are the signs of puberty if you got any of them then you've reached puberty pubic hair under armpit or on private parts -reaching the age 15 - having wet dreams please look at this for more information
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/197392/if-any-of-the-signs-of-puberty-appear-in-a-boy-he-becomes-accountable and I wouldn't recommend sinning before reaching puberty because it'll be harder for you to stop the sin after reaching puberty and your parents are responsible for your sins they aren't allowed to allow you to commit sins like these sins you start being responsible when you reach puberty